# jquery or logic failure only running half of or statement

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an action in Jquery run if either of 2 parameters is met

if select umodt = "Terminate" or "Delete"

however my logic is only firing when = "Delete" - please help

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#umodt select").change(function (e) {
      if ($(this).val() != "Terminate", $(this).val() != "Delete") {
        $("#disreas").hide();
      }
      else {
        $("#disreas").show();
          }

    });
  });
```

HTML referenced:

```
<div id="acttype"><table bgcolor="#CCCCFF" bordercolor="#000000" border="1" width="700"><tr><td colspan="6" align="center" border="1">Search Data:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="data">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search by:&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id="acttype" name="acttype"><option value=" "> </option><option value="Last Name">Last Name</option><option value="First Name">First Name</option><option value="Email">E-mail</option><option value="SSN">SSN</option><option value="Reset">Reset Conditions</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></table></div><div id="umodt"><table bgcolor="#CCCCFF" bordercolor="#000000" width="700" border="1"><tr><td colspan="6" align="center" border="1">  Or Select Action:&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id="umodt" name="umodt"><option value=" "> </option><option value="View">View Employee</option><option value="Add">Add Employee</option><option value="Edit">Edit Employee</option><option value="Delete">Delete Employee</option><option value="Terminate">Terminate Employee</option><option value="Sendemail">Send Message</option></select></td></tr></table></div><div id="emails"><table bgcolor="#CCCCFF" bordercolor="#000000" width="700" border="1"><tr><td colspan="2" align="center" border="1">   Enter Subject:&nbsp;</td><td colspan="8" align="center" border="1">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="sub" size="90"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" align="center" border="1">Enter Content:&nbsp;</td><td colspan="8" align="center" border="1">&nbsp;<textarea name="content" rows="7" cols="68"></textarea></td></tr></table></div><div id="disreas"><table bgcolor="#CCCCFF" bordercolor="#000000" width="700" border="1"><tr><td colspan="2" align="center" border="1"> Enter Reason:&nbsp;</td><td colspan="8" align="center" border="1">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="reason" size="90"></td></tr></table></div><table bgcolor="#CCCCFF" bordercolor="#000000" width="700"><tr><td colspan="10" align="center" ><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: use || instead of a comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)** instead of `,`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select#umodt").change(function(e) { 
    if (this.value != "Terminate" && this.value != "Delete") {
      $("#disreas").hide();
    } else {
      $("#disreas").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="acttype">
  <table bgcolor="#CCCCFF" bordercolor="#000000" border="1" width="700">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" align="center" border="1">Search Data:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="data">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search by:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select id="acttype" name="acttype">
          <option value=" "></option>
          <option value="Last Name">Last Name</option>
          <option value="First Name">First Name</option>
          <option value="Email">E-mail</option>
          <option value="SSN">SSN</option>
          <option value="Reset">Reset Conditions</option>
        </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="umodt">
  <table bgcolor="#CCCCFF" bordercolor="#000000" width="700" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" align="center" border="1">Or Select Action:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select id="umodt" name="umodt">
          <option value=" "></option>
          <option value="View">View Employee</option>
          <option value="Add">Add Employee</option>
          <option value="Edit">Edit Employee</option>
          <option value="Delete">Delete Employee</option>
          <option value="Terminate">Terminate Employee</option>
          <option value="Sendemail">Send Message</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="emails">
  <table bgcolor="#CCCCFF" bordercolor="#000000" width="700" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" border="1">Enter Subject:&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="8" align="center" border="1">&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="sub" size="90">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" border="1">Enter Content:&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="8" align="center" border="1">&nbsp;
        <textarea name="content" rows="7" cols="68"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="disreas">
  <table bgcolor="#CCCCFF" bordercolor="#000000" width="700" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" border="1">Enter Reason:&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="8" align="center" border="1">&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="reason" size="90">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<table bgcolor="#CCCCFF" bordercolor="#000000" width="700">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="10" align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unsure why but this syntax has changed it to not even show on Delete

Comment: HTML has been added - I apologize it is 1 line; it is created by PHP and still being cleaned up

Comment: @JamesStafford : updated the answer, you need and not or

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (

use || instead of a comma):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#umodt select").change(function (e) {
      if ($(this).val() != "Terminate" || $(this).val() != "Delete") {
        $("#disreas").hide();
      }
      else {
        $("#disreas").show();
          }

    });
  });
</script>
```